# Using Path in Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am using a Path in AndEngine that allows a sprite to be moved to a specific location providing the X and Y coordinates.

i have a cloud attached to my scehe, and i want the cloud to move back and forth from side to side but not exceeding the camera, on the X axis(which would be horizontal in landscape mode).

Here is what i have so far:

```
Sprite cloudSprite = new Sprite(50, 300, (TextureRegion)this.cloud);
final Path path = new Path(10).to(50,300).to(100, 300);

cloudSprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new PathModifier(10, path)));
```

This doesnt work correctly though, ive tried changing the X, and Y to parameters but to no avail.

Anyone know how i could get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a `PathModifier` for this purpose; Use `MoveXModifier` instead.

```
final float minX = 0;
final float maxX = CAMERA_WIDTH - cloudSprite.getWidth();
final float duration = //Duration for the full move across the screen here.
final MoveXModifier rightMoveModifier = new MoveXModifier(minX, maxX, duration);
final MoveXModifier leftMoveModifier = new MoveXModifier(maxX, minX, duration);
cloudSprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new SequenceModifier(rightMoveModifier, leftMoveModifier)));
```

(Here we assume the cloud is placed in the left of the screen when the game loads)

This should work.

Comment: Thanks jong! Can you tak a look at this? Its a issue ive been having since i just cloned the new GLES2 andengine repositiory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694727/type-enum-is-not-generic-error-cloning-andengine/8694744#8694744