# Type enum is not generic error cloning andengine

Tags: java, android, eclipse, andengine

I keep getting this error after cloning a repository from the AndEngine project..

> The type Enum is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <BoundsSplit>

Here is the class where the error persists.

```
package org.andengine.util.spatial.adt.bounds; //The error points at the beginning of this line.
import org.andengine.util.exception.AndEngineException;

/**
 * (c) Zynga 2011
 *
 * @author Nicolas Gramlich <ngramlich@zynga.com>
 * @since 21:13:32 - 11.10.2011
 */
 public enum BoundsSplit {
// ===========================================================
// Elements
// ===========================================================

TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT, BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM_RIGHT;

// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Getter & Setter
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Inner and Anonymous Classes
// ===========================================================

public static class BoundsSplitException extends AndEngineException {
    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7970869239897412727L;

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Inner and Anonymous Classes
    // ===========================================================
}
```

}

EDIT:

Here is more on what the error says

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type java.lang.Enum cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
- The type Enum is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
 <BoundsSplit>
- The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
- The type java.lang.Enum cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
```

Comment: When you declare members inside an `enum` in Java, declaring the appropriate constructor within that `enum` is mandatory which is *`always`* `private` whether you explicitly declare it `private` or not. Did you supply an appropriate constructor within your `enum`?

Comment: All i did was clone a repository from https://github.com/twalkerjr22/AndEngine and the error kept coming. Ive never gotten it before.

Comment: Check out the new edit i just added

Comment: I've had this error once, not sure how I solved it though. I'll have a deeper look now.

Comment: Please do, its putting my project on hold! =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it seems that this error has many causes. The main one from searching the web ([Here](http://www.google.co.il/search?rlz=1C1CHHJ_iwIL436IL436&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=The%20type%20java.lang.Enum%20cannot%20be%20resolved.%20It%20is%20indirectly%20referenced%20fromrequired%20.class%20files)) is that the `.classpath` file in the project directory is wrong - that's the one I had, too. It's probably AndEngine's project who has the wrong file, because you said this problem was encountered when you updated it.

So, you can either:

1. Solve it. [This](http://www.adriancourreges.com/articles/the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-with-eclipse/) page has a nice explanation of the problem, check it out. You can get more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734680/the-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenced-from-r).
2. Instead of importing AndEngine source into your workspace in eclipse (Which I guess you did, because that's probably the source of the problem), you can just link the source folder, then eclipse won't bug checking the AndEngine project files (Which might be wrong).

Another reason might be because of mis-configured JRE system library. There is a nice tutorial of how to fix that [here](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2009/06/eclipse-build-errors-javalangobject.html).

By the way, this problem is related to eclipse, so I'll retag your question with `eclipse` tag, so if my answer won't help - at least you will get better ones :)

Comment: Dude! I swear you are a LIFESAVER! The last link about the JRE system library missing!! Thanks man!

Comment: One more question, are we suppose to use the new AndEngine GLES2 as a jar or library? If so how do we use it as a library? http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/use-andengine-as-a-android-library-project-not-as-a-jar-t6142.html

Comment: Nicholas said we should not use it as a jar, so don't. You can either use it as an Android Library Project - http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects or just link the source folder, I do that and it works fine.

Comment: Do you have Google talk or any type of instant messaging?

Comment: I had, but I'm not using these too often so I usually forget the password :( You can contact me through email though (Take the email from my SO profile)